# Insert issue while trying with not exist operator in oracle

Tags: oracle

Trying to insert values if particular column value not exist in table

I have tried with sub query in where statement

```
INSERT
INTO ANIMALDATA VALUES
 ( 
   ( SELECT MAX(first)+1 FROM ANIMALDATA
   )
   ,
   'Animals',
   'Lion',
   10,
   '',
   '13-06-2019',
   'STOP'
 )
where not exists 
(select NAMES from ANIMALDATA where NAMES='Lion');
```

If the lion not exist then do insert statement should run

Give me an idea what i am missing as i am a beginner to oracle queries. help me to proceed further. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a condition, I think you need to do an INSERT INTO...SELECT:

(UPDATE: the CREATE TABLE statement is there to provide simple test data. It is not part of the solution).

<strike>create table animaldata(first, kingdom, names, num, nl, dte, s) as</strike>

select 1, 'Animals', 'Tiger', 11, 'a', '13-06-2019', 'STOP' from dual;

```
INSERT 
INTO ANIMALDATA select 
   ( SELECT MAX(first)+1 FROM ANIMALDATA
   )
   ,
   'Animals',
   'Lion',
   10,
   '',
   '13-06-2019',
   'STOP'
from dual
where not exists 
(select NAMES from ANIMALDATA where NAMES='Lion');
```

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

Comment: Hi Steve you have added create table and query in the beginning of the query why is that Stew as i am new would you please more specific. Thanks Steve

Comment: TO be more specific I just need to insert if the lion not exist in the column NAMES Steve

Comment: The CREATE TABLE statement is not part of the solution. I used it to create test data so anyone can test my solution. I have updated my answer to limit confusion.

Comment: "TO be more specific I just need to insert if the lion not exist in the column NAMES Steve " It's STEW not STEVE. I understand your need. My solution meets that need. Did you try it? Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Awch..!! my bad Stew, please do not mind and i have tried your query and got result as zero rows inserted , and it works fine i guess as lion value already exist in the table it is not get inserted. Thanks for your time. and one more doubt Stew, be right back in one moment

Comment: Thanks much again Steve for helping me out and as a beginner your input is valuable to me. Thank you so much Stew.

Answer (score 0):

please try below. Thanks,

```
INSERT
INTO ANIMALDATA a
select 
   ( SELECT MAX(first)+1 FROM ANIMALDATA
   )
   ,
   'Animals',
   'Lion',
   10,
   '',
   '13-06-2019',
   'STOP'
from dual
where not exists 
(select 1 from ANIMALDATA b where b.NAMES='Lion' and a.NAMES = b.NAMES );
```

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Thanks Nick for your time, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use `max(<value>) + 1` to come up with new values for a column - that does not play well with concurrent sessions.

Instead, you should create a sequence and use that in your inserts.

Next, if you are trying to do an upsert (update the row if it exists or insert if it doesn't), you could use a MERGE statement. In this case, you're trying to insert a row if it doesn't already exist, so you don't need the update part.

Therefore you should be doing something like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE animaldata_seq
 START WITH     <find MAX VALUE OF animaldata.first>
 INCREMENT BY   1
 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999
 CACHE 20
 NOCYCLE;

MERGE INTO animaldata tgt
  USING (SELECT 'Animals' category,
                'Lion' animal,
                10 num_animals,
                NULL unknown_col,
                TRUNC(SYSDATE) date_added,
                'STOP' action
         FROM   dual) src
  ON (tgt.animal = src.animal)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (<list of animaldata columns>)
  VALUES (animaldata_seq.nextval,
          src.animal,
          src.unknown_col,
          src.date_added,
          src.action);
```

Note that I have tried to specify the columns being inserted into - that's good practice! Code that has insert statements that don't list the columns being inserted into are prone to errors should someone add a column to the table.

I have also assumed that the column you're adding the date into is of DATE datatypee; I have used sysdate (truncated to remove the time part) as the value to insert, but you may which to use a specific date, in which case you should use `to_date(<string date>, '<string date format')`

Comment: Excellent comments. I simply answered the question as asked without going the extra mile. Just two things: first, you need a comma after "unknown_col", and second, when testing your code I get "ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here"

Comment: D'oh! Thanks for that!